# Xcode: Custom TTF font is not available even though it's added to target

Tags: xcode, fonts

I have a custom font called Bebas Neue that I want to add to my project. However, when I add these lines to print out the available font list, it doesn't show up:

AppDelegate.m

```
  for (NSString* family in [UIFont familyNames]) {
    NSLog(@"%@", family);

    for (NSString* name in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName: family]) {
      NSLog(@"  %@", name);
    }
  }
```

[image]

Resources folder:

[image]

Added to target

[image]:

When I check in the console, it is identical to HelveticaNeue, which is another font I added that works:

Helvetica Neue (working)

```
➜  ICOPro git:(master) ✗ ag Helvetica ios
ios/ICOPro/Info.plist
49:             <string>HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold.ttf</string>

ios/ICOPro.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
26:             2EB9EE9250BA4D41B0A7B61B /* HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold.ttf in Resources */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = 7F92E629CCFE4
A4DB2E601C5 /* HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold.ttf */; };
370:            7F92E629CCFE4A4DB2E601C5 /* HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold.ttf */ = {isa = PBXFileReference; explicitFileType = undefined; fi
leEncoding = 9; includeInIndex = 0; lastKnownFileType = unknown; name = "HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold.ttf"; path = "../src/assets/fonts/Hel
veticaNeue-CondensedBold.ttf"; sourceTree = "<group>"; };
556:                            7F92E629CCFE4A4DB2E601C5 /* HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold.ttf */,
1160:                           2EB9EE9250BA4D41B0A7B61B /* HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold.ttf in Resources */,
```

Bebas Neue (not working)

```
➜  ICOPro git:(master) ✗ ag Bebas ios
ios/ICOPro/Info.plist
60:             <string>BebasNeue-Regular.ttf</string>

ios/ICOPro.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
50:             56A87C895ECF4E1CBC2ADE48 /* BebasNeue-Regular.ttf in Resources */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = CF68AC43D8894DE0BC1E1C7
D /* BebasNeue-Regular.ttf */; };
393:            CF68AC43D8894DE0BC1E1C7D /* BebasNeue-Regular.ttf */ = {isa = PBXFileReference; name = "BebasNeue-Regular.ttf"; path = "..
/src/assets/fonts/BebasNeue-Regular.ttf"; sourceTree = "<group>"; fileEncoding = undefined; lastKnownFileType = unknown; explicitFileType
= undefined; includeInIndex = 0; };
567:                            CF68AC43D8894DE0BC1E1C7D /* BebasNeue-Regular.ttf */,
1172:                           56A87C895ECF4E1CBC2ADE48 /* BebasNeue-Regular.ttf in Resources */,
```

Comment: works for every font besides bebas neue for some reason. I switched to bebas (not neue) and it worked

Answer (score 0):

works for every font besides bebas neue for some reason. I switched to bebas (not neue) and it worked